# Google SUMIFS Formula with multiple (variable) OR Values (Array?)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

first and for all i love stackoverflow, helped me already alot of times. Now i have to ask a question because i havent found a solution that worked for me (or iam too dumb to build my formula).

I have a Google sheets Document with different sheets that get me some KPI from our Recruiting Software as daily export.

Iam trying to get the KPI for Applications, inProgress, hired, rejectecd for a specific Time.
Here is a list of the Different sheets and what i need from them:

"entrance_channel_report" - here i get the applications(K:K), inProgress(L:L), hired(M:M), rejected(N:N) for the different channels (for example: offline, indeed, email and so on (A:A) - its one of the sumifs criteria and jobnumbers (D:D)

i have already created aFilter for the Date Range to filter the Jobnumbers (Problem: i dont have Date Values on "entrance_channel_report" so i need to get them from "application_action_report")

```
=unique(filter(application_action_report!F:F;application_action_report!B:B>=C$88;application_action_report!B:B<=$D$88))
```

C88 is starting date (for example: 01.01.2023)
D88 is end date (for example: 31.01.2023)

this will get me a list like this (Jobnumbers - from application_action_report!F:F)

1044828
1143030
1150512
1104727
1162880
1104761
1169224
1169205

my formula i tried was

```
=SUMIFS(entrance_channel_report!$K:$K;entrance_channel_report!$A:$A;E$89;entrance_channel_report!$D:$D;{1044828;1143030}))
```

E$89 is the entrance channel (for example: email)

the last part does not work, not with cell Range or with the filter formula. This need to be an OR part where he adds all the jobnumbers from filter

here is a test spreadsheet [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZN3Ul_QxiMWOzgA9-swdlTl2XjYrl37Cv44W4TK2WyU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks :)

searched stackoverflow and tried to applied the found solutions

searched web and tried to apply too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one *approach*:

```
=let(Σ;unique(ifna(filter(application_action_report!F:F;isbetween(application_action_report!B:B;C1;D1))));
       sum(ifna(filter(entrance_channel_report!K:K;xmatch(entrance_channel_report!D:D;Σ);entrance_channel_report!A:A=E1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works on the Test Sheet but not on my worksheet. After some troubleshooting it looks like my "workaround" for a timestap is causing the Problem
on "application_action_report!B:B" is a custom import Formula
```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(MID(importrange("xxxx";"SGBewerberEreignis!I2:I");1;10)));"")
```
the source Format is like this "2020-10-08T10:39:47.459"

btw. awesome work my friend :)

Comment: Figured it out, the Sheet iam pulling from was a JSON export because of the data import limitations of google and all values in all rows where TEXT, with a simple ARRAYFORMULA and VALUE the Import for one needed ROW worked :)